# How to modify data after validation in React form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

I have a simple form where the user can input a url like `example`, `example.com` or `https://example.com`. I only accept `example.com` but I want to keep the user free to write what he want.

I wrote a simple `onSubmit` handler in order to check the domain the user wrote:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
  setIsBusy(true);
  const target = event.target as typeof event.target & {
    domain: { value: string };
  };
  const domain = target.domain.value;
  const hasSuffix = domain.endsWith(".com");
  const hasHttpPrefix =
    domain.startsWith("http://") || domain.startsWith("https://");
  const completeUrl = `${hasHttpPrefix ? "" : "https://"}${domain}${
    hasSuffix ? "" : ".com"
  }`;

  const domainRegex =
    /^(https|http)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.com/;
  if (!domainRegex.test(completeUrl)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsBusy(false);
    setIsError(true);
  }

  // now the form should submit ?domain=example.com
  target.domain.value = `${completeUrl.split("//")[1]}`;
};

<form method="get" onSubmit={handleSubmit} action="/">...</form>
```

The validation success, but if the user input `example` without the `.com` ecc, the `form` send `?domain=example`.

I would like the form to send the data I set with the `.com`, how is It possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `useState` did the trick.

`setInputValue(completeUrl.split("//")[1])`